How I can load model and inference using Libtorch (C++)?
I trained simple model for MNIST using it https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/cpp/mnist/mnist.cpp
I added code for saving model like below
string model_path = "model.pt";
torch::serialize::OutputArchive output_archive;
model.save(output_archive);
output_archive.save_to(model_path);

and in other cpp file, I just tried like below
torch::jit::script::Module model;
model=torch::jit::load("model.pt");
model.to(device);

std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
inputs.push_back(torch::ones({1, 1, 28, 28}));

at::Tensor output = model.forward(inputs).toTensor();
std::cout << output << std::endl;

It complied well, but had an error while executing
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'c10::Error'
  what():  Method 'forward' is not defined.
Exception raised from get_method at .../include/torch/csrc/jit/api/object.h:111 (most recent call first):
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string) + 0x57 (0x7f8e0163f897 in .../lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: c10::detail::torchCheckFail(char const*, char const*, unsigned int, std::string const&) + 0x64 (0x7f8e015efb25 in .../lib/libc10.so)
frame #2: <unknown function> + 0xa729 (0x560eaa26e729 in ./example-app)
frame #3: <unknown function> + 0xa8b1 (0x560eaa26e8b1 in ./example-app)
frame #4: <unknown function> + 0x5355 (0x560eaa269355 in ./example-app)
frame #5: __libc_start_main + 0xe7 (0x7f8d8eea0c87 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
frame #6: <unknown function> + 0x4bca (0x560eaa268bca in ./example-app)

How can I fix it?
I tried to use  TORCH_MODULE to create a module holder and save the model like this ref : https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/libtorch-how-to-save-model-in-mnist-cpp-example/34234/5
but it didn't work (maybe I used it wrong)

You have pushed your model to the device, but you have not pushed your input tensor to the device, try inputs.push_back(torch::ones({1, 1, 28, 28}).to(device));

@FlyingTeller Thank you but still same error occered
